# string::length() returning garbage value

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, string-length

I am trying to use `string::length()` inside a function I wrote, named `match()`, but I'm getting garbage values.

Why does the marked line is outputting garbage values?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

void match(string st1,string st2)
{
    for(int i=0;i<st1.length();i++)
    {
        cout<<"Why this value is garbage "<<(i-st1.length()-1)<<"\t";
        // this expression gives wrong values ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    }
}

int main()
{
    string st1,st2;
    cout<<"Enter the required string\n";
    cin>>st1>>st2;
    match(st1,st2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you please add the output you get?

Comment: What do you mean _"garbage"_? You're substracting length from `i` and wonder why gou get a negative value: `i-st1.length()-1`?

Comment: The title of your post is misleading. length() works fine, your expression (i-st1.length()-1) is wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

imagine a string "foo":

`i-st1.length()-1` means:

when i is 0:

```
0 - 3 = -3
  - 1 = -4
```

but `st1.length()` is a `size_t`, which is unsigned, so all terms in the expression are promoted to unsigned values.

```
(unsigned)0 - (unsigned)3 = 0xfffffffffffffffd
                      - 1 = 0xfffffffffffffffc

                          = 18446744073709551612
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that i is an `int` value, while [string::length](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/length/) will return you a `size_t` value. The first one is a signed value, while the second is unsigned. One way to prevent this is to cast your st1.length() as an `int`, so all the elements in your operation are signed values. You will then get the value you are looking for.

```
i-(int)st1.length()-1
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not garbage, you are implicitly converting/promoting a `signed` type (`i` is `signed int`) to an 'unsigned' one (the return type of `length()` is `size_t` which is `unsigned`).

It happens implicitly because an `unsigned type` is **more powerful** than a `signed one`. This is a common source of bugs in the C/C++ world.

This is what you need to modify:

```
cout<<" **NOT** garbage "<<(i-(int)st1.length()-1)<<"\t"<<endl;
```

Happy programming!